# What should i do with this data?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, c#-4.0

I have an application for the Windows Phone Mobile that will have multiple Mp3 Files.
 Example:
 263Mb, 03:04:50(Play Time)

I want to find a solution to hosting this data at no cost or how to implement something like this properly in the Mobile environment.

So far i have thought of:

When the application starts, it will install the media to isolated storage and stay there throughout the access of the applications content.

This function would not be preformed every time it starts but at the first initial start up.

Am i looking at this incorrectly or maybe you have a better solution?

Would love some advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum size of a XAP package is 250 MB, so you cannot package your mp3 file in your application. The only way seem to be downloading or streaming it.

Comment: Do you know of a way of Streaming it that wouldn't cost me to host? As well, Thank you for your answer! This was what i was looking for.

Comment: @KeeanoMartin look for a free webhosting with sufficient bandwith

Comment: Or recode in AAC so that the files are smaller...

Comment: Wouldn't even know how to start with AAC haha One last question i have  a MySql Database created on a free host but i dont know how to access it or start building data. Should i use REST? and if so whats the best way to implement that and quickly so i can get this app out sooner then later.